# Errors on downloaded project

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2013

I am getting over 1000 errors on a project I downloaded from tfs. I had to redownload it because i got a new pc.  My old pc had the exact same code as this but it worked perfectly.

Most of the errors are type or namespace.

Other error is The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' is either not registered in the machine or appplication config file or could not be loaded

I must be missing something.

Comment: Sounds like your references and COM objects have not been loaded into the project.

Comment: And you have to install the mysql connector for .net ;)